# 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT'

Tags: java, mysql

I have a **mysql** database on **Netbeans** and I want to see that view data but I have `a error 1064 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT'` . how can I fix ? thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Some google foo lead me to this:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66659

That bug report sound pretty much like your problem - there is no good fix for
you. But there is a lead for some more reading.

The similarity to you problem:

1. It's also the jdbc driver involved
2. The error message is the same
3. the problem occurs on a very recent mysql server version

So I tried to find the problem in the mysql-connector-java sources and found
the statement in `StatementImpl.java` in version 5.1.18 - an older version can be
found here:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/StatementImpl.java.html

Look for "`SET OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT`" in the file and you will find
it.

I also checked the most recent version

I checked the source of mysql-connector-java 5.1.22 and the problem seems to be fixed:

```
SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT
```

So suggested fix for the user: Please download the newer version of connector/j
and modify the driver entry in databases.

Suggested fix: Update bundled connector/j version

Comment: Can anyone please give a brief description of  the steps to update the connector/j version?

Comment: In theory you should just need to modify the jars on your classpath to add the new version (downloaded from MySQL website).  In my case, I had to switch `mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar` (existing version) to `mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar` (newly downloaded) and that fixed the problem.

Comment: BTW, the version that fixed this particular bug was [5.1.20](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/en/news-5-1-20.html).

Comment: This saved me hours of research! Just a version bump of the mysql driver from 5.1.16 to 5.1.26 was all that it needed to get rid of this problem

Comment: I am using mysql connector version 5.1.44 and still getting same issue. Can I use connector version 5.1.26 with mysql version 5.7.19?

Answer (score 8):

Found the answer from another question... The steps are quite straightforward.

1. Download latest jar file from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=412737.  Unzip it Copy jar file "`mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar`" to this folder: `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3\ide\modules\ext`
2. In Netbeans IDE: Disconnect from database. Click Services. Expand Drivers. Right-click on MySQL and press Customize. Add latest driver Remove previous driver.

Re-connect to dabatase within IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart the MySql server(WAMP, XAMP). Resolved my issue.

If you are using glassfish, upgrade to version 4.1,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass this error by setting my own limit on the query. This worked for me because I had full control over the sql statement. By specifying the limit myself it did not rely on the 'default'. I also made sure to end the query with a ';' but not sure if that made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The thing I notice is that if you have several connectors in the same place, BO will take the first one he found like you can see in these images.

[image: WEBI doesn't work with connector 5.0.8 evenif Designer do]

[image: BO take the first SQL connector he found]