# Unable To Change Preview Setting In Eclipse BIRT Report Designer

Tags: eclipse, birt

I've just begun using the BIRT report designer for Eclipse to create reports from data in a MySQL database. When attempting to preview the result set from a created data set, I receive the following error:

> SQL error #1:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=500' at line 1

I understand that this syntax is invalid with MySQL, as it should be

```
SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=500
```

However, I cannot figure out if/where I can make this correction, as it is added automatically by the report builder when generating the preview.

Furthermore, in the IDE preferences, I have selected the 'No Limits of number of rows to display' option, trying to bypass this statement altogether, but continue to receive the same error, indicating that it still is trying to preview 500 or less rows, even after deleting the first data set definition and remaking it after the option was changed and restarting Eclipse.

If anyone has any suggestions for either changing the syntax or getting the No Limits option to work correctly, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Was able to determine source of bad syntax and added it as answer. However, I am still unsure why the Limit statement is being added to the query by the preview generator after selecting the 'No Limit' option, so I will be leaving the question open in the hopes that someone else may be able to provide an answer to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was actually able to figure out the issue with getting the correct syntax thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669270/option-sql-select-limit-default) SO post regarding Netbeans. The MySQL JDBC driver simply needed to be updated. Preview no longer generates depreciated syntax.

Comment: As indicated in the comment I left to my question, I am hoping that someone can address the unresolved portion of my question, as I think that would be a better, more general answer than the one I provided. However, if no further answers are put forward in the next day or two, I will accept this answer.

Comment: This fixed my problem as well. 5.1.18 had the problem, versions 5.1.25 and 5.1.37 both fixed it. Note that until I restarted Eclipse I continued to get the syntax error, even after editing the Data Source. I guess the old jar was still loaded in memory.

Comment: @user3351605 The "Max number of rows to fetch" setting is applied when the Data Set is used in a report. And the Preview pane does obey that limit if its less than 500, but only previews the first 500 otherwise. I strongly suspect it was wired that way so that users don't crash the IDE with large data queries. (That's not unreasonable for a _preview_ pane I guess, but I was as confused by it as you.)