# Tibco Service JDBC SQL deployment issue

Tags: jdbc, tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

I have created a Service running on Tibco, containing a JDBC-enabled process within it, and tested it successfully. The database server is MySQL, and is hosted remotely. When connecting to the remote DB from the service hosted on my machine, the SQL is executed well, but after building the Tibco EAR file and deploying to another external machine, then trying to access the same remote DB  server using the same credentials, the external machine returns the below  error upon returning:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1
```

So, a few questions:

1. What could be the cause of the above error, given the DB being accessed is the exact same one, using same SQL query, but from different machines?
2. Is the JDBC driver used for development compiled as part of the packaged EAR file?
3. Does the JDBC driver being used in a Tibco Process depend on the Tibco service installed or on the packaged EAR file?

Am asking from a learner PoV as am currently picking up Tibco

Comment: what mysql jdbc driver version is used and what is mysql server version ?

Comment: here is similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669270/option-sql-select-limit-default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like jdbc driver issue. You may have different mysql driver version in tibco designer and BusinessWorks.

You don't need to add jdbc driver to your ear package.
Please note that you can specify mysql driver in your package classpath. In tibco Administrator PackageName->Configuration->ServerSettings->Prepend to ClassPath or Append to Class path.

You can also try to copy the driver from your tibco designer(in BW5 it's in \tibco\bw\5.11\lib\ 
) to the BusinessWorks classpath

[image]

Comment: It was a different package issue like you said, but I had to add an updated driver jar file to my EAR file so it could pick from there. I did not have access to the backend of the BW server I was hosting on and it did not have the latest driver package.

Comment: just FYI: it's probably not a good idea to add jar files to EAR file itself especially if it's utility or driver jars that can be used from different packages. you should avoid creating big (in size) EAR files which not only take a lot of time to deploy, but they may also cause deploy timeouts on the Administrator. This topic can be helpful [Including JARs with deployment](https://community.tibco.com/questions/including-jars-deployment)